# Is there a performance or memory benefit : Select A, B, C into temp from query VS Select into temp from (Select A,B,C from table) as TTable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

In Sql server (2008 version), 
I have two queries like this :

```
Select * from sampleTable into #tempTable
```

OR

```
Select * into #tempTable from (Select Query) as someTableName
```

Is there performance or memory space benefit in any of these queries ? or both are equally good.

This is known that they individually are better than

```
Insert into Temp 
<Query>
```

But how about when compared to each other.

**Updated Text :** 
Two queries are like this:

```
 Select A,B,C into #tempTable from TestTable
```

OR

```
Select * into #tempTable from (Select A,B,C from TestTable) as someTableName
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Performance questions are usually product specific.

Comment: @jarlh Sql server 2008

Comment: I doubt there are any differences.

Comment: I have been told that in the second query the inner select query creates in memory table and hence it is a burden on the memory. I also feel they both are same. So posted the question here to confirm this understanding.

Comment: "I have been told..." - don't believe everything you're told. Queries are compiled and optimized as a whole - the *system* decides what order to perform operations in, *whether* to perform spools (writing temporary caches of data), etc. If you have two queries which are *logically* the same, but expressed differently, then if the optimizer is doing it's job well, you *should* end up with exactly the same execution plan.

Comment: *"This is known that they individually are better than `Insert into Temp  <Query>`"*.... Is it? What is the basis of this assumption? Also you have been told incorrectly, for starters the first query is not valid syntax

Comment: Also, as a general comment - don't try to learn prescriptive rules for writing "performant" code - there are far too many situations where trade-offs occur which mean that something you've decided is "the most performant" will not be in a particular situation. Write *clear*, readable code. Set performance *goals*. Then *measure* the performance of your code, and if its acceptable, move on.

Comment: @GarethD - Hi , thanks for the info i have corrected the syntax in the updated text. So is one of them better than the other in terms of performance or memory.

Comment: @GarethD - Regarding your comment about the "Insert into" statement. what i meant was select into is preferred because temp table is not required to be defined prior hand and it is created on its own. Before using  insert into temp table, the temp table needs to be declared. hence writing less code is one of the advantange.

Comment: Nope. The actual queries you have posted will generate the same execution plan. I could not agree more with what @Damien_The_Unbeliever has said though, for as many rules as you make and remember about performance, you will have to remember twice as many exceptions to those rules. Then you will need to relearn all the exceptions and rules when you change DBMS. This isn't a bad thing, but unless you have actual performance issues you can end up bogged down for hours trying to shave milliseconds off a query that already runs in under a second...

Comment: @GarethD : Yes. Makes sense. Probably i took it on my ego when somebody pointed out that the second query is not better code what i wrote and first one is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those result in the same query plan.

SQL Server has a query optimizer, and optimizing away redundant columns is about the easiest and most basic optimization there is.

The best way to answer such questions for yourself is to look at the query plans and compare them. It is generally quite pointless to memorize the performance behavior of specific queries. It is a better approach to understand how queries are optimized and executed in general.

Comment: Hey thanks. I get your point that queries can be looked through the execution plan and make changes where ever necessary. Better way rather than learning the should and musts in query writing which can become tedious job.

Answer (score 0):

Same performance

if you are going to use very large datasets like 10000, then #temptable slows down the query, if you are using this for paging or something there is groupby and in newer versions fetch newxt rows methods